# Clear multi-line input in IPython

Tags: command-line, shell, python, ipython

The current line on the IPython prompt can be cleared with the keyboard shortcut Ctrl-U. Is there any shortcut that clears all lines on the IPython prompt in one go?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CTRL-C`, which cancels the current action and it works in this situation as well. There are other useful keybindings, but some apparently don't work when you use vim mode. In vim normal mode you can already do all those things easily but in insert mode `CTRL-C` is quite practical.

Answer (score 0):

The usual suspect here is the keyboard shortcut `CTRL-L` that is used on most terminals to clear all lines (to clear the whole terminal). Works on Linux Python command line interfaces.

`CTRL-L` is also quoted as a shortcut to clear all lines in [this](https://cmdlinetips.com/2013/01/eleven-ipython-keyboard-shortcuts-to-move-around-easily/) article.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, if I try this shortcut everything in the terminal gets cleared *except* for the lines I've just entered. Quite the opposite from what I intended :p. Using Windows here by the way!

Comment: @JJS can you try `CTRL-SHIFT-L` then? or ALT, perhaps? The `L` key should partake in the key combination. If that is what happens to you, then you just need to find the key combination for the inverted operation - which shouldn't be too far from `CTRL-L`. If that does not work then I believe there is no keyboard shortcut for that in Windows, as there is no keyboard shortcut equivalent for the `cls` command.